# is there a function in R to quickly calculate the difference between two geom_bin2d maps?

Tags: r, histogram, difference

I have a large 2-variable dataset that may be classified into 2 groups using a third variable. Overplotting is an issue, so I've resorted to visualizing my data using bin2d and other similar approaches. I would like to calculate the difference between the binned counts of the two groups and visualize that as well (e.g subtract one 2d histogram from another).

example code:

```
df <- diamonds
df_color_H <- filter(df,color=="H")
df_color_E <- filter(df,color=="E")

ggplot(df_color_H)+
  geom_bin2d(aes(carat,price),bins=40)

ggplot(df_color_E)+
  geom_bin2d(aes(carat,price),bins=40)
```

Ultimately, I want to visualize the difference between overlapping bins. I know the solution is likely a pre-processing step before bringing them into GGplot but I haven't found exactly what I'm looking for. I also don't need a sophisticated solution using KDEs or something like that.

Any suggestions would be welcome!

Comment: histogram is supposed to plot a distribution, hence counts are positive values. What if the difference between bin counts are negative? It's nonsense.

Comment: In this case, a negative number would indicate that there are more of one population than the other at that particular cell. That would still be important information. I think I'm using the wrong jargon and search terms; that's probably why I've had so much trouble